# BASH execute command on remote server

Tags: arrays, bash, ssh

I want to execute a command which return all user's home directory that exist and store the result into bash variable

```
res=$(ssh -q -o LogLevel=error user@server << 'EOF' 
t=$(awk -F':' '{ if ( $3 >= 500 ) print $1 }' /etc/passwd)
readarray -t res_array <<< "${t}"
UHOME="/home"
for u in "$res_array"
do
  _dir="${UHOME}"/"${u}"
  if [[ -d "$_dir" ]]
then
    echo "$u"
  fi
done
EOF
)
```

locally the code works but not on remote server
I used echo $u for store the resultat home user exist to the variable :(

Comment: `for u in $res_array` should be written as `for u in "${res_array[@]}"`

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
res=$(ssh -q -o LogLevel=error user@server << 'EOF' 
t=$(awk -F':' '{ if ( $3 >= 500 ) print $1 }' /etc/passwd)
readarray -t res_array <<< "${t}"
UHOME="/home"
for u in "${res_array[@]}" # change this line
do
  _dir="${UHOME}"/"${u}"
  if [[ -d "$_dir" ]]
then
    echo "$u"
  fi
done
EOF
)
```